# Validation Accuracy incorrect when multiple outputs are in the dense layer!

Tags: classification, keras, lstm, accuracy, multi-output

I have a set-up a parallel LSTM architecture with two LSTM layers and one Dense layer producing several outputs which are converted into a probability with a sigmoid function on the dense layer. For each time-series I provide binary labels which are supposed to be used for training the model. Since I have been seeing a discrepancy between the "val_accuracy" provided by the model in the epoch iteration and my own calculated "val_accuracy", I am asking myself where the inconsistency lies. I have built the following class in order to track the problem:

```py
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.x_test)
        m = metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
        m.update_state(y_true=self.y_test, y_pred=y_pred)
        val_accuracy = m.result().numpy()
        if val_accuracy > self.val_accuracy:
            self.val_accuracy = val_accuracy

        bce = losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
        loss = bce(y_true=self.y_test, y_pred=y_pred).numpy()

        print('val_loss: {} val_accuracy: {} at epoch: {}'.format(loss, val_accuracy, epoch))
```

the val_loss I calculate perfectly matches the val_loss generated in the epoch iteration, however my "val_accuracy" is different than the "val_accuracy" produced by Keras. In the one-dimensional case my "val_accuracy" matches the Keras "val_accuracy". I am sure that my val_accuracy is correct. Keras overestimates it massively. I have set the shuffle option to False for the adam-Optimizer.
Would appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: The shape of my output (y) is (batch_size, number of time-series). If the shape is (batch_size, number of time-series, 1) then the val_accuracy seems to be calculating correctly. As already said the bce function produces the same result irrespective of the shape.